# Low Feature Importance Scores but High Precision/Recall?

Tags: classification, random-forest, scikit-learn

I am running a heterogeneous classification model with numeric, categorical, and unstructured text data to predict a binary response.

The data suffers from class imbalance hence I decided to perform over-sampling to help with this.  After fitting the model I was checking the "feature importance" from the random forest and the results are extremely low yet my precision/recall via classification report on the test set are fairly solid (test set does not have over-sampled observations)

```
    # pl

    TOKENS_ALPHANUMERIC_HYPHEN = "[A-Za-z0-9\-]+(?=\\s+)"

    catTransformer = Pipeline(steps=[
        ('cat_imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='constant', fill_value='missing')),
        ('cat_ohe', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))])

    numTransformer = Pipeline(steps=[
        ('num_imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='constant', fill_value=0)),
        ('num_scaler', StandardScaler())])

    textTransformer_0 = Pipeline(steps=[
        ('text_bow', CountVectorizer(lowercase=True,\
                                     token_pattern=TOKENS_ALPHANUMERIC_HYPHEN,\
                                     stop_words=stopwords))])

    textTransformer_1 = Pipeline(steps=[
        ('text_bow', CountVectorizer(lowercase=True,\
                                     token_pattern=TOKENS_ALPHANUMERIC_HYPHEN,\
                                     stop_words=stopwords))])

    FE = ColumnTransformer(
        transformers=[
            ('cat', catTransformer, CAT_FEATURES),
            ('num', numTransformer, NUM_FEATURES),
            ('text0', textTransformer_0, TEXT_FEATURES[0]),
            ('text1', textTransformer_1, TEXT_FEATURES[1])])

    PL = Pipeline(steps=[('feature_engineer', FE),
                         ('RF', RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=-1, class_weight='balanced'))])


    RGS = {"RF__max_depth": [100, None],\
                  "RF__n_estimators": sp_randint(10, 100),\
                  "RF__max_features": ["auto", "sqrt", "log2", None],\
                  "RF__bootstrap": [True, False],\
                  "RF__criterion": ["gini", "entropy"]}

    SKF = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5,\
      random_state=11,\
      shuffle=True)

    cv_model = RandomizedSearchCV(PL, param_distributions=RGS, cv=SKF, n_iter=25)
    cv_model.fit(X_train_OS, y_train_OS)


    from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix
    preds = cv_model.predict(X_test)
    print(confusion_matrix(y_test, preds))
    print(classification_report(y_test, preds))
    # class report

                  precision    recall  f1-score   support

         CLASS1       0.94      0.99      0.96      2428
         CLASS2       0.93      0.67      0.78       495

       micro avg       0.94      0.94      0.94      2923
       macro avg       0.93      0.83      0.87      2923
    weighted avg       0.94      0.94      0.93      2923

    # feature importance via sklearn RF classifier

    RF_IMPORTANCES = list(zip(cv_model.best_estimator_.named_steps["RF"].feature_importances_, X_train_OS.columns))
    RF_IMPORTANCES.sort(reverse=True)
    RF_IMPORTANCES
    [(0.044093125101590386, 'cat_feature1'),
     (0.03352702448927779, 'cat_feature2'),
     (0.01581719021567583, 'cat_feature3'),
     (0.012946183337756689, 'cat_feature4'),
     (0.008118877274266727, 'num_feature1'),
     (0.0020503812794265275, 'num_feature2'),
     (0.0007034562139435102, 'num_feature3'),
     (0.00036099370222021567, 'text_feature1'),
     (3.0835853057137074e-05, 'text_feature2')]
```

Does this mean these feature are completely irrelevant?

If so then how can the accuracy results be fairly decent?

Am I missing something?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your feature importance listing looks wrong to me. The `feature_importance_` array has is of the same length as the input to *the RandomForest*, and you seem to be expanding the feature-set through the pipeline.
I suspect that feature importance length is considerably bigger than the length of `X_train_OS.columns`. If so, your printout of the feature importance has the wrong length[1], and likely wrong names.

1. `zip` stops generating when the shortest of the input generators stop.